# "invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression is: [object Text]. It should be an element"

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

My goal is to print the entire wall of highlighted text below using Python Selenium.

[image]

When I right click on the text > Copy > Copy Full Xpath, I get:

```
/html/body/script[1]/text()
```

Attempt 1:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/script[1]/text()").text
print(element)

#ERROR:
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath 
expression "/html/body/script[1]/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

Attempt 2:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/script[1]").text
print(element)

#PRINTS BLANK
```

Attempt 3:

```
element = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/script[1]").text
print(element)

#ERROR: 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Attempt 4:

```
for element in driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/script[1]"):
    print(element)

#ERROR: 
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

Attempt 5:

```
for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/script[1]"):
    print(element)

#PRINTS: 
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="31e0e98bb28d49019385c0cff458fa02", element="e505e171-2ba5-4f29-beb2-ea99a7aa89e4")>
```

Attempt 6:

```
for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/script[1]"):
    print(element.text)

#PRINTS BLANK
```

Comment: What's the URL of the page?

Comment: @Unmitigated Unfortunately cannot share the URL as the page is behind a password.

Comment: Does selenium see the same html you see in browser?

Comment: Why don't you select it by id?

Comment: @sudden_appearance Thanks for the response. Can you explain how I can check this? What do you mean does selenium see the same html?

Comment: @Unmitigated When you said select by ID, do you mean something like: element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "__NEXT_DATA__").text

Comment: Selenium can be blocked by antirobot tools and it also has problems when page has javascript that is being executed onload and so on. You can simply print entire body to console by selecting body tag

Comment: @sudden_appearance When you said selecting body tag, are you referring to something like: driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tag name")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the HTML, you should be able to use

```
e = driver.find_element(By.ID, "__NEXT_DATA__")
print(e.get_attribute("textContent"))
```

---

The reason for the error is that you can't use an XPath that ends in `/text()` because that returns a text node but `.find_element()` expects the return to be a web element.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This printed blank. Any suggestions on what I can try next?

Comment: Updated the answer. I've tested it and this works.

Comment: Worked ty. Can you explain how you came up with this? Is there documentation?

Comment: `.text` gets the visible text. Since the SCRIPT tag text isn't visible, I switched to a JS property, [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).